# Compare and jump instruction as one instruction

Tags: assembly, nasm

Is there a way I can compare and jump in one instruction:

C code:
 1. `while(i<10)`
 2. `{i++}`

Assembly code: `(eax=0)(ecx=10)`

1. `.while:`
2. `cmp eax, ecx`
3. `jge .endofwhile`
4. `add eax, 1`
5. `jmp .while`
6. `.endofwhile:`

Is there a way i can do line 2 and 3 in one instruction?

Comment: The assembly code does not correspond to the C code (it does not loop).

Comment: You can also use `inc eax` instead of `add eax,1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have the test and branch treated as a single instruction, and the way to do this is to write them as two instructions like you did, to use a modern Intel processor and to follow a few simple rules (the branch instruction must be contained in the same 16-bytes line of code that the test instruction ends, the two instructions must not be separated by any other instruction, …).

The mechanism is called [macro-fusion](https://web.archive.org/web/20120922053925/http://www.behardware.com/articles/623-7/intel-core-2-duo-test.html). More detailed information including the precise conditions in which macro-fusion apply is available from Agner Fog's [manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf), page 82.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way i can do line 2 and 3 in one instruction?

If you're allowed to change your C code to count backwards:

```
1. i = 10;
2. while(--i >= 0);
```

Then you can use the (single) [LOOP opcode](http://intel80386.com/386htm/LOOP.htm).

LOOP is an old instruction though, so it may be deprecated on newer (Pentium++) CPUs: where by "deprecated" I mean, "still supported, but slower than using more primitive opcodes like  the ones given in Pascal's answer."

Comment: In "LOOP opcode" i see `LOOP rel8` what is "rel8"? Loop uses ecx in 32bit mode. So ecx must equal 10 before I use LOOP correct? (is rel8 a label to jump to?)

Comment: @WeigelGram rel8 specifies the type of the machine code operand or parameter, i.e. it's an 8-bit relative jump, i.e. you can jump forward or backwards 128 bytes in the code. In assembly language (not machine code), you specify that parameter as a label: the assembler calculates the location/distance of the jump for you and inserts that into the machine code (or displays an build-time error if the jump is further than 128 bytes).

Comment: @WeigelGram Yes, initialize ecx. Use it like this: `mov ecx,10` (number of loops) `top_of_loop:` (a label) `blah blah blah` (whatever useful instructions inside the loop) `loop top_of_loop` (decrement ecx and jump to top of loop unless ecx has reached 0)

Comment: Thanks ChrisW. Now I know a bit more assembly. Always good to learn new things.(and there is so much more I want to learn).